# How do I change the vertical bar in netrw?

Tags: vim, netrw

I just want to know if there is a way for replacing the | glyph with │ (notice that the second one is taller) in order to make a continuous vertical line in netrw...

I successfully replaced it in vim's split lines but I haven't found the way to do it in netrw.

Below an image is shown with what I got (green rect) and what I want (purple rect) in replace.

[image: current situation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not configurable via an option like `set fillchars` or a variable.

However, you can change it directly on `netrw.vim`. Just edit `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/netrw.vim` and change `s:treedepthstring`.

```
if has("gui_running") && (&enc == 'utf-8' || &enc == 'utf-16' || &enc == 'ucs-4')
 let s:treedepthstring= "│ "
else
 let s:treedepthstring= "| "
endif
```

From the code we can also see that if gui is enabled, it automatically uses the taller one.

Before:

[image: Default]

After:

[image: After changing]